# Errors when trying to update Debian 7 APT Cache

Tags: linux, debian, updates, debian-wheezy

When I'm trying to make update (with `apt-get update`) in Debian 7 I always have errors like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
```

I tried changing servers in `sources.list but` nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Try `apt-get clean`. That should clean the cache and then you should be able to do `apt-get update`.